# I want a code in vector format To print and display all C drive files

Tags: winapi, vector

I want a code in vector format
To print and display all C drive files
please help

Comment: What is `code in vector format`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enumerate the filesystem manually in your own code.  You can do whatever you want with each folder/file that the enumeration finds.

Look at the Win32 API [`FindFirstFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) and [`FindNextFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew) functions.

Or in C++17 and later, look at the [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) library, such as the [`std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) class.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the entire directory through [`FindFirstFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) and [`FindNextFileW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew) API, and add the file path in the data structure you need during the traversal process, such as vector.

Here is a sample:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> fileVector;
struct HandleWrapper
{
    HANDLE hFind;
    ~HandleWrapper() { if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) ::FindClose(hFind); }
} ;
void findFiles(const std::wstring& spath)
{
    HandleWrapper wrapper;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    std::wstring sourcepath = spath + std::wstring(L"\\*.*");
    wrapper.hFind = FindFirstFile(sourcepath.c_str(), &FindFileData);
    if (wrapper.hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            if (std::wstring(FindFileData.cFileName) == L"." || std::wstring(FindFileData.cFileName) == L"..") continue;
            std::wstring fullpath = std::wstring(spath) + L"\\" + FindFileData.cFileName;
            if ((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
            {
                findFiles(fullpath);
            }
            else
            {
                fileVector.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(wrapper.hFind, &FindFileData));
    }
}
```

This sample use a vector to save all files in the path, and then you can perform the subsequent operations you need.